# creating View from an existing table and maintain a relationship with new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these 2 database A(existing) and B (newly created). I have created 4 different table under Database B as per the requirement, whereas i am trying to retrieve the data(SSN, Fname, MI, Address, LName) from one of the table (demographics) from Database A (existing database). also i got to make sure that the relationship (Foreign key relation has to be maintained) has to be maintained between Demographic table and couple other tables from Database B. i am thinking of Creating a VIEW_demographic ( virtual table) and maintain relationship. Can someone please let me know if there are any other ways to do that? i would appreciate your help.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. Are you trying to establish a foreign key between databases? You can't do that using standard techniques. You could add a check constraint that includes a function. I would start asking though why you need separate databases if they are this tightly coupled. Seems to me different schemas might be better. Also, please tell me you aren't storing SSN in plain text. That should be encrypted at all times.

Comment: Sean Lange is right. Why do you need two different database with such coupling? Also, you will need to look into LinkedServer if you go that path.

Comment: Sean i have got this project to save the records from a info path form inserted at front end and there are several new data which has to be stored in the table. so to do so i have created a new database named DB B which has 6 tables . but there are some other fields like SSN, FNAME, LNAME stored in table demographics ( existing ) in DB A.  To do so, i have been thinking to create a staging table with all the column from multiple tables at table B and create relationship with as demographic table from DB A.

Comment: i completely get that creating a schema would have been better sine they are tightly coupled instead of creating a relationship between 2 diff database, but is it a good practice to add more schema to an existing database ??